# How to refer to other buttons in my xib file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button

I want a button action that will change the button title but also will change other buttons title, I don't know how to refer those buttons (I have 9 (3X3) buttons).

Is there anyway i can refer those by their tags?

Answer (score 1):

You can either [create an outlet to those buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779069/how-do-i-add-an-action-or-outlet-to-a-class-in-xcode-4-3-1), or grab them by their tag value:

```
UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:TAG_VALUE];
[myButton setTitle:@"New Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The preferred iOS way is to use outlets, but you may also use the tag value of the view you're grabbing.