# Why can't I create an Action in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, action, outlet

When I follow the instructions at [How do I add an action or outlet to a class in Xcode 4.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779069/how-do-i-add-an-action-or-outlet-to-a-class-in-xcode-4-3-1), or Apple's First iOS App tutorial, there's no option for Action. There is only options for Outlet and Outlet Connections. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can connect actions only to subclasses of `UIControl`.

You are trying to create an action from a **`UIView`**, which is not a subclass of UIControl and does not have actions.

Start the drag from the button, and not the "main view"

Comment: Thank you!  Just to clarify, I have to select the object before I start the control-drag, correct?