# I cannot see Storage or Action Connections in Xcode

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, iboutlet

**Solved** - Simply control-click your item outside of the braces instead of inside.

I am really new at programming in general. But, I am following a straightforward tutorial seen here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TP5NghkLY0M

At 1:55, you can see he control-clicks the UI Button into the ViewController.h

When I do that myself, I can only see "Outlet" under Connections. I cannot see Actions, or anything else...And I cannot see the Storage.

The image seen here is what I have on my computer

[image]

How do I make it so I can see more Connections, and can see the Storage area when I control-click over to the ViewController?

Thanks!

Comment: a UIImageView does not have any actions. Try with a UIButton. And what do you mean by storage area?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I create an Action in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730019/why-cant-i-create-an-action-in-xcode)

Comment: I get the same thing with the UIButton. I only see these 4 selections. Connection, Object, Name, and Type. I need to be able to see Event and Arguments for the UIButton... and I need to see Storage for the UIImage view. The guy in the tutorial has it how I want it. See the video at 1:40 to 1:55  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TP5NghkLY0M

Comment: have you tried to click on "Outlet" to open the drop down menu? And don't use the `{ }` area of the @interface as target. Drag to the area after the curly brackets.

Comment: Yes, of course. It sadly only has Outlet and Outlet Connection.

Comment: drag to the area after the curly brackets. where your other IBActions are.

Comment: Dragging outside the braces does not fix it. But thanks for all of these suggestions so far.

Comment: I take that back. Dragging outside the braces did fix it. Thank you.